# Thread in C not waiting as expected

Tags: c, pthreads

In my main function, I create a thread that executes pingOMS function. Following is code extract from my main function.

```
if (status = pthread_create(&agentPingThread,NULL,(void *) &pingOMS, NULL) != 0 ){
    LogError("%s: Failed to create the OM agent ping thread -- %s\n", prog,
strerror(status));        
}
```

This pingOMS function contacts server using sockets every 10 seconds by forcing current thread to wait by calling another function ThreadWait1 with in the pingOMS function. The function ThreadWait1 uses pthread_cond_timedwait to achieve this. Following is code for pingOMS:

```
int pingOMS(){
DEBUG("Inside %s %s() \n",__FILE__,__func__);

if(This.stopped || failedPings > 1){
    DEBUG("  Ping manager stopping ...\n");
    return TRUE;
}

int socketPING,returnHB;
returnHB = FALSE;
struct sockaddr_in serverADDRESS;
struct hostent *hostINFO;    
char remoteFILE[4096],recvBUFF[4096];

if ((hostINFO = gethostbyname(This.servername)) == NULL){
    failedPings++;
    LogError("Ping manager unable to reach OM Server.\n");
    if(failedPings < 2) goto SKIP_POINT1;        
    if(failedPings > 1){
        This.stopped = TRUE;
        return FALSE;
    }
}

if ( (socketPING = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    failedPings++;
    LogError("Ping manager unable to create socket.\n");
    if(failedPings < 2) goto SKIP_POINT1;        
    if(failedPings > 1){
        This.stopped = TRUE;
        return FALSE;            
    }
}

serverADDRESS.sin_family = hostINFO->h_addrtype;
memcpy((char *) &serverADDRESS.sin_addr.s_addr, hostINFO->h_addr_list[0], hostINFO-
>h_length);
serverADDRESS.sin_port = htons((int) This.serverport);

if (connect(socketPING, (struct sockaddr *) &serverADDRESS, sizeof(serverADDRESS)) < 0) {
    failedPings++;
    LogError("Ping manager unable to connect OM Server on port %d\n",
 (int)This.serverport);
    if(failedPings < 2) goto SKIP_POINT2;        
    if(failedPings > 1){
        This.stopped = TRUE;
        close(socketPING);
        return FALSE;            
    }
}else{
    DEBUG("  Ping manager successfully connected to OM Server on port 
%d\n",This.serverport);
}

sprintf(remoteFILE,"STARTPING|%d|%s|ENDPING",This.agentID,getOracleDate());    

if (send(socketPING, remoteFILE, sizeof(remoteFILE), 0) >= 0){
    DEBUG("  Server ping initiated.\n");
}else{
    LogError("Server ping failed. OM agent has lost connection to OM server.\n");
    failedPings++;    
    if(failedPings < 2) goto SKIP_POINT2;
    if(failedPings > 1){
        This.stopped = TRUE;
        close(socketPING);
        return FALSE;
    }
}                 


// Start - Following code interpret server ping status sent by OM server
int fr_block_sz = 0;
recvBUFF[0] = 0;
    while((fr_block_sz = recv(socketPING, recvBUFF, sizeof(recvBUFF), 0)) > 0){
        returnHB = TRUE;
        DEBUG("  Receiving ping data from OM server.\n");
    }       
    DEBUG("  Received buffer %s\n",recvBUFF);
    if(returnHB == TRUE){
        if(!strncmp(recvBUFF,"SUCCESS",7)) {   
            DEBUG("  Server ping succeeded.\n");                
        }        
        else{
            LogError("OM agent has lost connection with OM server and will shutdown.\n");
            failedPings++;
            if(failedPings < 2) goto SKIP_POINT2;
            if(failedPings > 1){
                This.stopped = TRUE;
                close(socketPING);
                return FALSE;
            }
        }                        
}else{
            failedPings++;
            LogError("OM agent has not received heartbeat from server.\n");
            if(failedPings < 2) goto SKIP_POINT2;
            if(failedPings > 1){
                This.stopped = TRUE;
                close(socketPING);
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

//End
SKIP_POINT2:       
close(socketPING);  
DEBUG("  Agent ping thread going into sleep mode ... \n");
SKIP_POINT1:
ThreadWait1(10000);
pingOMS();
```

}

Here is code for ThreadWait1:

```
void ThreadWait1(int timeInMSec)
{
DEBUG("Inside %s %s() \n",__FILE__,__func__); 
int rt;
pthread_mutexattr_t mtx_attr;
pthread_mutex_t mtx;
pthread_condattr_t cond_attr;
pthread_cond_t cond;

int milliseconds;

pthread_mutexattr_init ( &mtx_attr );
//pthread_mutexattr_settype ( &mtx_attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL );
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared ( &mtx_attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE );

pthread_mutex_init ( &mtx, &mtx_attr );
pthread_mutexattr_destroy ( &mtx_attr );

#ifdef USE_CONDATTR
pthread_condattr_init ( &cond_attr );
if ( pthread_condattr_setclock ( &cond_attr, CLOCK_REALTIME ) != 0 )
{
    fputs ( "pthread_condattr_setclock failed", stderr );
    exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

pthread_cond_init ( &cond, &cond_attr );
pthread_condattr_destroy ( &cond_attr );
#else
pthread_cond_init ( &cond, NULL );
#endif

    struct timespec now, ts;
        clock_gettime ( CLOCK_REALTIME, &now );

    ts.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + timeInMSec / 1000;
        ts.tv_nsec = now.tv_nsec + (timeInMSec % 1000) * 1000000;
    if (ts.tv_nsec > 1000000000)
    {
        ts.tv_nsec -= 1000000000;
        ++ts.tv_sec;
    }

    DEBUG ( " %ld.%09ld %ld.%09ld \n", now.tv_sec, now.tv_nsec,
             ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec );

    pthread_mutex_lock ( &mtx );
    rt = pthread_cond_timedwait ( &cond, &mtx, &ts );
    ASSERT(rt);

    pthread_mutex_unlock ( &mtx );
```

}

Problem :

Thread only waits for 4 ~ 5 seconds instead of 10 seconds but quite interestingly when same logic from the ThreadWait1 function in a standalone c program, it works well. Could it be related to thread scheduling on the CPU or something else.

Comment: Why not just call `sleep(10)` to make `pingOMS()` sleep the thread for 10s?

Comment: What is being returned from `pthread_cond_timedwait()`?  For a normal return, is should return `0` which should trip your `ASSERT()`.

Comment: Also (though probably unrelated to your problem), `ThreadWait1()` never cleans up `mtx` or `cond` (with `pthread_mutex_destroy()` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer for question but doubt in my mind. What platform you are using?

Secondly, Why you have created a recursive call, i think the ThreadWait1 should be calling pingOMS function after every X time (10 sec in your case).

Try the following code:

```
#include <unistd.h>


if (status = pthread_create(&agentPingThread,NULL,(void *) &ThreadWait1, NULL) != 0 ){
    LogError("%s: Failed to create the OM agent ping thread -- %s\n", prog,
strerror(status));        
}


void ThreadWait1()
{
    int timeInMSec = 10;
    while(1)
    {
        pingOMS();
        // Add your locks here if required
        sleep(timeInMSec);
        // release the locks if locked
    }
}
```

And remove the pingOMS(); call from pingOMS() function so that it doesnt call itself(No recursion)

Comment: its 32 bit linux with kernel 2.6.18-194.17.1.0.1.el5. My ThreadWait1 function only cause current thread to wait. If I don't  call pingOMS function recursive then after waiting for 10 second pingOMS function will complete and would not attempt for another ping.

Comment: Yes right my point here is Create a thread ThreadWait1 which is continuous running (i.e. while(1) ) and sleep the thread for 10 secs and then call pingOMS. Your current method may lead to out of memory error. as the function calls never completes. This might be also the root cause for your problem

Comment: I tried calling pingOMS within the ThreadWait1 but no change in behaviour. Do you reckon I should create another function pingThread which will have a while(1) loop that calls pingOMS and then ThreadWait1. Something like `while(1){pingOMS(); ThreadWait1(10000);}`. Then my main function will create thread something like this `pthread_create(&agentPingThread,NULL,(void *) &pingThread, NULL)`. I am not that good in C programming so I do appologize in advance something does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot, This worked but wondering why pthread_cond_timedwait behaved abnormally. I will be relying heavily on these pthread_cond_timedwait functions in my whole project especially when sleep function does not accept milliseconds.

Comment: for miliseconds you can use nanosleep as follows : `nanosleep((struct timespec[]){{0, 500000000}}, NULL);` this will make it sleep for half second